# R: converting vertical data to horizontal format with conditionals

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyr

I am trying to convert a data frame with a vertical format into a horizontal format. I'm familiar with the `dcast` function. However, I'd like to update the left hand side of the `dcast` equation with a conditional based on the fields that will become a row. Here is a specific example:

```
df = data.frame(ID=c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                Field=rep(c("Color","Height","Weight","Condition"),3),
                Values=c("blue",72,140,"ON","blue",72,180,"OFF","green",80,162,"OFF"))
```

[image]

You'll notice that if we aggregate only based on `ID`, there will be multiple matches because there are multiple values when Field is "`Condition`" (that is, `ID` `3` has both an `ON` and `OFF` condition for `Condition`). Thus, I'd like to first start by pulling that out as a column, and then applying `dcast`, to result in a dataframe like so:

```
desiredDF = data.frame(ID=c(3,3,4),
                       Condition=c("ON","OFF","OFF"),
                       Color=c("blue","blue","green"),
                       Height=c(72,72,80),
                       Weight=c(140,180,162))
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chop` to nest `Values` corresponding to each `(ID, Field)` tuple, spread `Field`s and `Values`, and `unnest()` aftewards:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  chop(Values) %>%
  spread(Field, Values) %>%
  unnest(-1)

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#      ID Color Condition Height Weight
#   <dbl> <fct> <fct>     <fct>  <fct> 
# 1     3 blue  ON        72     140   
# 2     3 blue  OFF       72     180   
# 3     4 green OFF       80     162
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How does this solution affect whether weight of 140 ends up in the ID 3, ON condition or the ID 3, OFF condition?

Comment: Thanks! But same question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `unstack()` + `cbind()`

```
dfout <- cbind(t(unique(t(unstack(df, ID ~ Field)))), unstack(df, Values ~ Field))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Color Color Condition Height Weight
1     3  blue        ON     72    140
2     3  blue       OFF     72    180
3     4 green       OFF     80    162
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How does this solution affect whether weight of 140 ends up in the ID 3, ON condition or the ID 3, OFF condition?

Comment: @CodeGuy what do you mean? can you explain a bit?

Comment: The weight value of 140 is on the row associated with ID 3 and Condition 'ON' rather than on the row associated with ID 3 and condition 'OFF'.

Comment: @CodeGuy but this code achieves the same result as your desired output in your post

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 tidyverse ways ways : old school and new school

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(ID2 = cumsum(Field == "Color") ) %>%
  spread(Field, Values) %>%
  select(-ID2)
#>   ID Color Condition Height Weight
#> 1  3  blue        ON     72    140
#> 2  3  blue       OFF     72    180
#> 3  4 green       OFF     80    162

df %>%
  mutate(ID2 = cumsum(Field == "Color") ) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from  = "Values", names_from = "Field") %>%
  select(-ID2)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      ID Color Height Weight Condition
#>   <dbl> <fct> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>    
#> 1     3 blue  72     140    ON       
#> 2     3 blue  72     180    OFF      
#> 3     4 green 80     162    OFF
```

We need to build ID2 here because your categoriescan't be understood by data alone, we need the human knowledge that there is a repeated sequence here. `ID2` makes it clear.

Comment: Thanks for these answers. How does this solution affect whether the weight of 140 ends up in the ID 3, ON condition or the ID 3, OFF condition, for example?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question,

Comment: The weight value of 140 is on the row associated with ID 3 and Condition 'ON' rather than on the row associated with ID 3 and condition 'OFF'. Why is that? How does the code determine this.

Comment: ID2 makes the groups explicit, and under these groups 140 and ON are in the same group. Try executing the pipe chain by steps if it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to use `dcast` you could do the following (below). This would allow for duplicate values for each `ID`. The `key` added would use `Color` to define a new row of data in your desired final data set, based on how the data is currently organized.

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(df), ID + ave(key <- Field == "Color", ID, FUN = cumsum) ~ Field, value.var = "Values")
```

**Output**

```
   ID key Color Condition Height Weight
1:  3   1  blue        ON     72    140
2:  3   2  blue       OFF     72    180
3:  4   1 green       OFF     80    162
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How does this solution affect whether weight of 140 ends up in the ID 3, ON condition or the ID 3, OFF condition?

Comment: With `cumsum` in this example, in the order of the rows of data, when `Field` is `Color` a new `key` is added. So in this example of your raw data, the first row is `Color` (first key), and all rows after this are associated with this `key` including the weight of 140...then when `Color` is reached again (second key), all rows after including weight of 180 are associated with this second key...

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So it's basically just based on the order of the rows in the original data frame.

Comment: Correct - it uses the order of the original data frame. Personally, I like the `tidyverse` solutions and utilize those most often. But thought this post was worth adding in case you wanted to pursue `dcast` instead...